# Left switch on gang light pair not getting power

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch

I’m trying to install a set of light switches to control my fan and lights. The left switch has two black cables running to it and the right has a red and black.

I installed both switches and the left doesn’t power on when I flip the breaker. I’ve confirmed it isn’t a manufacturing issue with one of the switches by uninstalling/reinstalling them in the reverse order. In both cases, the left side is the one not receiving power.

Below are the original and new configurations, respectively:

[image: Original Configuration]

[image: New Configuration (Left side not getting power)]

The new red wire on the left connects to the nest of black wires similarly to the original bottom black wire. I’m afraid what may happen if I reverse the wires going to the red and black on the left switch, though I don’t know whether that will do any actual harm.

Any clear issues with how I rewired these?

Comment: The guide also mentions the switches are only compatible with a one-way, single-pole circuit. I had to do some reading, but I don’t believe I’m looking at a three-way circuit, am I?

Comment: Difficult to be sure, but it looks like you have LINE & LOAD reversed on the left switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reverse the line and load on the left switch

Comment: Is there any risk to reversing them to see? If that’s the case I’m guessing it didn’t matter what side line/load were configured on the original switches so left and right were configured differently?

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks for the help!

Comment: They do not designate line and load on a single toggle like these.

Answer (score 8):

These new smart switches are active devices, and *power themselves* between supply (their black) and neutral (their white obviously).  Therefore they care about the difference between supply (their black) and switched/lamp power (their red).  Your old switches didn't care about that.

You need the smart-switch black (supply) to go to the bundle of black wires.  The smart-switch red (switched) must go to the lamp/fan, which are the red and black that go into the same cable.

Remember, **do not dim a motor**.  Motors respond very badly to triac style dimming intended for lights, they need a different type of thing called a fan speed control.

Comment: That’s great advice. Fortunately these are switches and not dimmers, but you stopped me from trading them in for a dimmer set instead, so thank you.